# How to fill Facebook form 'what's in your mind?' using selenium with Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver

I am doing a simple web automation testing.
I'm trying to write something on facebook textare 'What's in your mind?'.
The HTML code I need to fill is the textarea with placeholder 'What's in yopur mind?'.
I access the page in the image below and this is the code I tried:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//textarea").send_keys('ciao')
```

And this the error I got:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <textarea id="composer-placeholder-textarea" class="_5whq input _3gik" name="xc_message"> is not reachable by keyboard
```

I use this user agent:

```
'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.2 Safari/537.36'
```

And this is the window where textarea is located:
[image]

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

try this solution :

```
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/")
x=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='mount_0_0']/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/span").click()
x.send_keys('ciao')
```

Comment: it says 'unable to locate element' unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

I finally got a solution. The page has two textareas, one is not scrolled into view, and another one that is what interests us. We need to interact with the second one, in my case the textarea which has the id

```
uniqid_1
```

instead the textarea was confusing me has the following id:

```
composer-placeholder-textarea
```